# Is C++/CLI an extension of Standard ISO C++?

Tags: c++-cli, iso

Is Microsofts [C++/CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI) built *on top* of the C++ Standard (C++98 or C++11) or is it only "similar" and has deviations?

Or, specifically, is every ISO standard conforming C++ program (either C++98 or C++11), also a conforming C++/CLI program?

Note: I interpret the Wikipedia article above only comparing C++/CLI to MC++, not to ISO Standard C++.

Comment: I had to use it once and did not enjoy the experience. (In the end I took the Java / JNI route rather than C#). I'd say it's a deviation. The `^` pointer stuff is, in my opinion, vulgar and doesn't sit well with `std::shared_ptr` of C++11. The answer to your second paragraph is certainly no.

Comment: @Bathsheba from my rough reading of the wikipedia article it might be that `^ptr` is a different thing then `*ptr`, as in managed vs unmanaged. Like `!Finalizer` vs `~Destructor`. Both could still be on-top of Std-C++. Thanks for the beauty-comment, but my question is not about beauty ;-)

Comment: @Bathsheba shared_ptr works fine enough in CLI programs, after you write a proper adapter for it. Same goes for std::function for instance. CLI isn't all that bad of an experience once you have some adapter/conversion boilerplate code in place: then it's imo by far the easiest way to bridge .Net and C++ apps - that being said, the latter is also the sole reason I'd ever consider using CLI again, it excels at it, but for the rest it's more like *meh*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CLI is a set of extensions for standard C++. CLI has full support of standard C++ and adds something more. So every C++ program will compile with enabled CLI, except you are using a CLI reserved word and this is the weakness of the extension, because it does not respect the double underscore rule for extensions (such reserved words has to begin with `__`).

You can deactivate those extensions in the GUI by:

> Configuration Properties -> General -> Common Language Runtime Support

Even [Bjarne Stroustrup calls CLI](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq.html#CppCLI) an extension:

> On the difficult and controversial question of what the CLI binding/extensions to C++ is to be called, I prefer C++/CLI as a shorthand for "The CLI extensions to ISO C++". Keeping C++ as part of the name reminds people what is the base language and will help keep C++ a proper subset of C++ with the C++/CLI extension

Language extensions could always be called deviations from the standard, because it will not compile with a compiler without CLI support (e.g. the `^` pointer).

Comment: Cannot be an extension unless it compiles every standard-conformant program with the standard-mandated semantics. Which is **not the case**. (Striving for high compatibility does not mean achieving full compatibility. Anyway, Managed C++, the precursor, was discontinued because its adherence to the C++ standard made it too cumbersome.)

Comment: Most extensions break compatibility in some way, but most respect the two underscore rule for additional reserved words. I don't think, that this fact alone is sufficient to classify CLI as "non-extension".

Comment: There is a really simple way it could have been an extension instead of just a derivate, by useing only implementation-private symbols, and if so desired, add an include-file which changes them to nicer symbols. Also, there are quite a lot of common real extensions to C and C++: Their existence does not in any way change the behavior of any conforming program. For a list of some common ones, you might want to look at C-standard annex J (Most are also common for C++).

Answer (score 8):

Sure, it is an extension to C++03 and can compile any compliant C++03 program that doesn't conflict with the added keywords.  The only thing it doesn't support are some of the Microsoft extensions to C++, the kind that are fundamentally incompatible with managed code execution like __fastcall and __try.  MC++ was their first attempt at it, kept compatible by prefixing all added keywords with underscores.  The syntax was rather forced and not well received by their customers, C++/CLI dropped the practice and has a much more intuitive syntax.  Stanley Lippman of C++ Primer fame was heavily involved btw.

The compiler can be switched between managed and native code generation on-the-fly with `#pragma managed`, the product is a .NET mixed-mode assembly that contains both MSIL and native machine code.  The MSIL produced from native C++ source is not exactly equivalent to the kind produced by, say, the C# or VB.NET compilers.  It doesn't magically become *verifiable* and doesn't get the garbage collector love, you can corrupt the heap or blow the stack just as easily.  And no optimizer love either, the MSIL gets translated to machine code at runtime and is optimized just like normal managed code with the time restrictions inherent in a jitter.  Getting *too much* native C++ code translated to MSIL is a very common mistake, the compiler hides it too well.

C++/CLI is notable for introducing syntax that got later adopted into C++11.  Like `nullptr`, `override`, `final` and `enum class`.  Bit of a problem, actually, it begat `__nullptr` to be able to distinguish between a managed and a native null pointer.  They never found a great solution for *enum class*, you have to declare it *public* to get a managed enum type.  Some C++11 extensions work, few beyond the ones it already had, *auto* is fine but no lambda expressions, quite a loss in .NET programming.  The language has been frozen since 2005.

The C++/CX language extension is notable as well, one that makes writing C++ code for Store and Phone apps palatable.  The syntax resembles C++/CLI a great deal, including the `ref class` and hats in the syntax.  But with objects allocated with `ref new` instead of `gcnew`, the latter would have been too misleading.  Otherwise *very* different from C++/CLI at runtime, you get pure native code out of C++/CX.  The language extension hides the COM interop code that's underneath, automatically reference-counting objects, translating error codes into exceptions and mapping generics.  The resemblance to C++/CLI syntax is no accident, they basically perform the same role.  Mapping C++-like syntax to a foreign type system.